# How to port an Android app in Blackberry With Push Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, blackberry-10, blackberry-push

i am an Android developer and and Want to port my Android app in Blackberry 10.
in my android app i have a promotion feature in which i use push notification to show current promotion. and when user click on it, it opens browser to show promotion.
ok this is the working of my app.
now i want to ask how to port this app in Blackberry with that push notification feature.
is it possible.
any tutorial or example for this.
i have already read how to convert/port Android App in Blackberry on Blackberry's Developers site.
but is it possible with push notification feature?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can. Check [Creating Push-Enabled Android Apps](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html). You can't use Android C2DM, but you can do the same using BB10 push service.